Does style dictionary necessarily need to work with token-transformer?
I'm working with tokens studio https://docs.tokens.studio/tokens/documentation-tokens and I was wondering if token-transformer https://www.npmjs.com/package/token-transformer is really necessary to work with style dictionary?
According to the documentation, "transform-tokens" converts Tokens Studio tokens for Figma into a format readable by Style Dictionary, eliminating any mathematical operations or aliases, yielding only raw values. However, Style Dictionary appears to function well when directly reading tokens from Tokens Studio's input/tokens.json.
As a precaution, I'm using the token generated by transform-tokens located in outputs/tokens. I've noticed some differences: all colors are in hexadecimal and variables without values disappear in the token generated by Style Dictionary. I'm wondering if it's still worthwhile to use transform-tokens when Style Dictionary seems to work fine without it?
This raises the question of whether transform-tokens adds significant value if Style Dictionary can already process Tokens Studio tokens directly.
I don't know if the thread will be of interest to anyone, but if it is, thanks in advance :)
